# Modifying a multilayer network plot in pymnet

Tags: python, visualization, network-analysis, pymnet

I want to visualise a multilayer network using [pymnet](http://www.mkivela.com/pymnet/visualizing.html). The example in the package's [documentation](http://www.mkivela.com/pymnet/visualizing.html) shows how to plot a multilayer network (left-hand side of the plot below) but I would like to add another layer (*orange*) that would be displayed at a similar level as the *blue* layer. I know how to add another layer but it would be above the *blue* layer. What I need is a layer that's next to my current plot.

The original plot can be created using:

```
from pymnet import *
fig=draw(er(10,3*[0.4]),layout="spring")
```

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve it in *pymnet*? If not, is there another package that could draw this plot?

Comment: The **pymnat** library is not available on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pymnet). How do you install it? Which repository?

Comment: The source code is available in [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/bolozna/multilayer-networks-library). The code quality needs to be improved… Package dependencies are missing… There are a lot of awkwardness… IMO, this lib is more a proof of concept than a production-ready library. Consider using something else.

Comment: As I can see in the source code (`pymnet/visuals/drawnet.py`), a figure is just a stack of vertical layers. You cannot have two stacks side by side.

Comment: thanks. do you know of another package that could draw this plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution where you only use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) to create your multi-layer graph, and where you calculate the node positions by your own.

For the purpose of this explanation, we create a small graph of 30 nodes randomly.

The layers are sub-graphs with additional properties: (*x*, *y*) coordinates and a color.
The coordinates are used to position the layers relatively in a 2D grid.

```py
import networkx as nx

# create a random graph of 30 nodes
graph = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(30, .2, seed=2019)

# Layers have coordinates and colors
layers = [
    (nx.Graph(), (0, 0), "#ffaaaa"),
    (nx.Graph(), (0, 1), "#aaffaa"),
    (nx.Graph(), (0, 2), "#aaaaff"),
    (nx.Graph(), (1, 2), "#ffa500"),
]
```

Each layer is populated with the nodes of the main graph.
Here, we decided to split the nodes list in various ranges (the start and end index of the nodes in the graph).

The color of each node is stored in a *color_map*.
This variable is used later during graph plotting.

```py
import itertools

# node ranges in the graph
ranges = [(0, 6), (6, 15), (15, 20), (20, 30)]

# fill the layers with nodes from the graph
# prepare the color map
color_map = []
for (layer, coord, color), (start, end) in zip(layers, ranges):
    layer.add_nodes_from(itertools.islice(graph.nodes, start, end))
    color_map.extend([color for _ in range(start, end)])
```

Then, we can calculate the position of each node.
The node position is shifted according to the layer coordinates.

```py
# Calculate and move the nodes position
all_pos = {}
for layer, (sx, sy), color in layers:
    pos = nx.circular_layout(layer, scale=2)  # or spring_layout...
    for node in pos:
        all_pos[node] = pos[node]
        all_pos[node] += (10 * sx, 10 * sy)
```

We can now draw the graph:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Draw and display the graph
nx.draw(graph, all_pos, node_size=500, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Graph with layers]

Of course, you can work with a 3D-grid and use a projection to have a 3D-like preview.

Comment: Hi @Laurent LAPORTE. I saw this question and your answer. I posted a question on pymnet. I do not know if you know the answer and you can help me on that, but if you could just have a look at that, I would appreciate it. Many thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66947554/how-to-change-color-of-nodes-in-a-network