# How to change color of nodes in a network?

Tags: python, networkx, pymnet

I would like to change the color of nodes within the column `A`:

```
    A                       B                   Score      Value    
0   user1               test1                    6.6        A
1   user1               user241                  3.2        AA
2   user241             test1                    4.8        B
3   user12              test4                    3.1        C
4   user1               user23                   2.9        A
```

To create the network I am using mnet:

```
from pymnet import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnet = MultilayerNetwork(aspects=1)
for index in df.index:
      mnet[df.loc[index, 'A'], df.loc[index, 'B'],'friendship','friendship'] = 1
fig=draw(mnet, show=True, figsize=(25,30))
```

I think I should change the color within `draw()`, but I do not not the command. No matter which color should be used, as what it is important is that all the users in `A` can have the same color (different from that in `B`). Some user within `A` may be also in `B`.

I would do something like this:

```
for node in mnet:
    if node in df["A"].values:
        colors.append("red")
    else: colors.append("green")
```

But I do not know how to add such info in `fig`.

Comment: I think it should be something to this: `nodeColorDict`. But I do not know how to assign a color if nodes are just present in the column. Reference: http://www.mkivela.com/pymnet/visualizing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [pymnet.draw()](http://www.mkivela.com/pymnet/autogen/pymnet.draw.html), `nodeColorDict` is a dictionary keyed by node-layer.

```py
colors = {}
for node in mnet.iter_node_layers():
    if node[0] in df["A"].values:
        colors.update({node: "red"})
    else:
        colors.update({node: "green"})

fig = draw(mnet, show=True, figsize=(25,30), nodeColorDict=colors)
```